# Rooted the phone and installed cyanogenmod. How to get back Sense UI?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-desire, htc-sense

I have a HTC Desire comes with Sense UI when bought. I rooted it and installed Cyanogenmod. Is there anyway I can get back my Sense UI. I don't mind removing Cyanogenmod.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're going to need to install a Sense-based ROM. CyanogenMod is basically a customized build of the Android Open Source Project (AOSP) code, which is released in source form by Google. They use only open source components, and Sense is a proprietary, closed source UI made by HTC.

Installing a ROM with Sense is very easy, though. The procedure will be just like flashing CM - boot into recovery and flash a .zip file with the ROM that you want (alternatively, install via [ROM Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager&hl=en), whatever you prefer).

There are custom Sense ROMs as well as "stock" rooted ROMs floating around. [The XDA boards](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=628&order=desc) have a handful of each. You can find a rooted stock ROM [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=773997), though, if you're looking to go back to the original system as provided by HTC (but retaining root).

**Edit:** I answered this under the assumption that you have no backups to work with, but if you used ClockworkMod to create a backup of your system before installing CM7 (which is highly advised for any future readers out there!), you can restore that backup and...well, be back where you were on a stock rooted system. After all, that's the point of the backup!

Comment: I tried what you said. It worked nicely, except I can't get online using my 3G data plan. Do I need to do any other step as well? Has this got anything to do with Radio?

Comment: Actually I found out why. Had to add the correct APN.