# Rooted, cyanogenmod. How to get back Sense UI from Titanium Backups?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-sense, titanium-backup, htc-incredible-s

Similar to [Rooted the phone and installed cyanogenmod. How to get back Sense UI?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/8474/274) but with the addition of full backups of the old Sense UI packages.

I am running Cyanogenmod 7 on a rooted HTC Incredible 2. I have Titanium Backup copies of all the original HTC Sense UI packages. When I try to restore some of them, Titanium Backup brings up the "Restoring  ..." dialog but it just sits there with the message up. It never goes away, Android does not try to Force Close it, and the message also stays in the Notification bar until the app is manually closed via a task killer. (The system still responds; just Titanium Backup that seems to hang.)

How do I restore these system packages to get the Sense UI and widgets back?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is impossible. You can only use  Sense UI  on a ROM that incorporates it. To regain it you will either need to return to your stock HTC ROM or see if there are any other ROMS that support Sense.

Comment: Just to expand on this answer. HTC's Sense, Sansung's TouchWiz, Motorola's BLUR, etc., are not just simple Launcher replacements. These overlays are very deeply integrated into base Android OS in such a way that they replace many (if not most) internal functions, apps, and framework. CyanogenMod ROM is based on AOSP, which doesn't have any of the internals required by Sense, and is therefore incompatible with it. By the time you incorporate these internals into CM, there would be very little of CM left, and you'd be back to Stock Sense ROM.